# How to parse csv file uploaded via file and show the content in result view in Zend

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form

I am using **Zend 1.12**

I have a form which has two fields: email, and file

My index view shows the form. And after validation is successful, I want to parse the csv file and show the content on result view:

My Code:

IndexController:

```
class IndexController extends Zend_Controller_Action {

  public function init() {
    /* Initialize action controller here */
  }

  public function indexAction() {
    // action body
    $form = new Application_Form_FileUpload();
    $form->submit->setLabel('Upload');
    $this->view->form = $form;

    if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
        $formData = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
        if ($form->isValid($formData)) {

            $file = $form->getValue('file');
            $email = $form->getValue('email');


           //$this->_helper->viewRenderer('result', null, true);

           //$this->_helper->redirector('result', 'index','', array('email' => $email, 'file' => $file));
           $this->_helper->redirector->gotoRouteAndExit (array(
                'controller' => 'index',
                'action'     =>'result',    
                'name'      => $file)); 

        } else {
            $form->populate($formData);
        }
    }           
  }

  public function resultAction() {
    $email = $this->_getParam('name');
    $this->view->email = $email;
  }
}
```

My index view:

```
    <?php 
            $this->form->setAction($this->url(array('action' => 'index')));
            echo $this->form;
        ?>
```

My result view:

```
    <?php
       echo $this->email;
       //echo the content of the csv file;
    ?>
```

My result view is empty always.

What is the correct/right way to get the form data, and if validation is successful, show the content in result view.

Edit: I have succeeded to get parameters passed to resultaction. 
I just was looking into different file. That is why it was not showing up.

But still, is it the right way to do it for my case? For it seems not correct.

Comment: formatting and grammar

Comment: Please show us the route definition for the `resultAction()`. Does it have a named parameter named `name`?

Comment: What do you mean by routedefinition? the result view is also added.

Comment: If there is no custom route for that action, then I guess you are using the default route: of the form `/:controller/:action((/:k1/:v1)/:k2/:v2)` etc. So, What is the url displayed in the browser location bar when you are taken to the page for the `resultAction()`? Based on the updated info, you seem to be ok now. Re: your updated question: post and then redirect is generally the right thing to do.